# Package only certain directories with asar in an Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge, asar

I have an Electron application where I am trying to use [asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) to package the node_modules and sources directories excluding the other directories.

I noticed when building the application with `asar` enabled, the whole app directory is packaged. This is not ideal because some executables and DLL's need to be available outside the asar file.

### What I've tried

Currently, I have a script that packages the sources and node_modules directories (using asar). This script is executed after Electron-Forge has built the executable. But Electron does not seem to automatically check the asar file for source and node_module files. I receive the error `"Error: Cannot find module index.js"`. This gives the wanted file structure, but does not work with Electron (see "File structure" below).

### File structure

File structure before creating executable:

```
- node_modules/
- sources/
- executable/
- images/
```

Wanted file structure after creating executable:

```
- resource/
   - app/
      - executable/
      - images/
      - sources.asar
      - node_modules.asar
```

or the following (where the `app.asar` file should only contain the `sources/` and `node_modules/` directory):

```
- resource/
   - app/
      - executable/
      - images/
   - app.asar
```

And it's mainly important that Electron knows when to use the `asar` file and when to use the files directly. Is it possible to configure it like this, or something similar?

### Question

Is there any way to configure Electron/Electron-Forge to only package certain directories into asar files while copying the other directories into the resource/app directory?

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` in `"build"` section add the following code:

```
"build": {
  "asar": true,
  "asarUnpack": [
    "**/thefirstfolder/secondfolder/**/*"
 ],
},
```

This `"**/thefirstfolder/secondfolder/**/*"` will unpack everything that is the child of `secondfolder`